# How to pad real-valued sequences

Tags: tensorflow, sequence-to-sequence

I have several sequences of univariate real-valued time-series data. The sequences are of different lengths and right now I cannot batch them and feed them to a network.
What is the correct procedure to pad these sequences? Is it even possible in this case since I can't use any number as a special symbol?

**UPDATE 1**

I'm working with arbitrary univariate time-series data (not related to one specific domain, unbounded range). To give example of one such a series consider standardized stock dataset (only first 10 elements shown):

```
d = array([-0.37807043, 0.14321786, -0.37807043, 0.13478392, 0.18733381,
   1.19576774, 0.25675156, 0.26064414, 0.30930144, 0.38650436])
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think your question is open ended, can you give some example or sample sequence for better understanding. Accordingly we can suggest you better. Thank you!

Comment: Updated my question. However, the time-series I'm working with are arbitrary.

Comment: I think that combining such data together is not going to give you good insights. In the scenarios where you want to combine different time series data, you need to check for the trend of the data and if they both are similar then it makes sense to combine them or else it is very wrong to do it.

Comment: My aim is to implement a time-series autoencoder presented in a conference paper and later use these seq-embeddings to improve classification/regression performance.

Comment: hmm I understand, even I'm also working on something similar, since I don't have the future values, I forecast the values and these are used for classifying the target outcome. But combining data on which you don't have enough support(proof) is wrong way of doing. This is what I feel.

Comment: My initial idea was that training the sequence auto-encoder on arbitrary time-series data would 'force' it to learn general characteristics of the time series - maybe shape, maybe extract periodicty, trend, or a combination of more (can't say in advance). 
However, to get back to the original problem, let's assume I'm working with one kind of a data only (e.g. stock prices). How would I pad these sequences?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74853/discussion-between-toros91-and-aechlys).

Answer (score 0):

How you pad it (and even whether you do so) would depend on what you expect of the data. This imposes boundary conditions on the data which will induce artifacts in any transform you make. How bad this effect depends on how well geared your data is to accepting a particular padding method.

Padding methods include zero padding or a periodic bound.

Padding doesn't have to be done in the time domain. Eg interpolating in the frequency domain and back transforming allows you to extrapolate.

If your analytics has a finite history (eg FIR filters) then you can isolate time regions where padding is unnecessary and draw comparisons therefrom.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have several univariate time series, that you want to stack into a multi-variate one, but cannot do so because they have different length. I think you might find this guide on [masking and padding](https://keras.io/guides/understanding_masking_and_padding/) to be a useful starting point. In your case I think masking is a must have as you will have batches when one or more series needs to be padded. An alternative is to train an imputer model first, to impute missing time series from those that are left.